# Can the results of an problem invalidate the process and therefore themselves?

Tags: logic

For example, suppose that to solve an equation, one must divide both sides by *x*, and it is later discovered that *x* = 0 (and zero was a permissible value in the original equation). What would this mean for the equation and/or results?

Comment: Let us take a simple example, $x(x^2+2)=x$. This has the obvious solution $x=0$. Now look for **non-zero** solutions. In the search for such a solution, division by $x$ is permissible. So such a solution must be a solution of $x^2+2=1$, which in the reals is impossible. There is no issue: we have found all the solutions.

Comment: I'd think there would be other, similar cases.

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of such cases. The logic is always the same. When we divide by $x$, we are confining attention to the non-zero solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's worth me giving a similar answer to the above (which is very good, and which I upvoted!) just to restate it with a different, more abstract emphasis...

In any attempt to make a *logical deduction* ("the set of solutions is exactly 4, -7.3 and 0"), you are **forbidden** from making any step which *just maybe could* be invalid. Therefore, your situation would not arise because the division is forbidden unless it is known to be legal.

Of course, when you're solving the problem you don't know whether 0 is possible or not, and so you need some way to check it out either way. We do this by considering both possibilities separately, in *cases*. This means adding an assumption, say "$x\neq 0$", and then continuing. You find results or contradictions, and you can deduce what the answer is. How?

Logically, you're now on firm ground, with a pair of statements like
$$x\neq 0\implies x=6,-3.7,0$$
and
$$x=0\implies x=7,-6$$

Then you look at what you've got. In the first case, we discover $x=6,-3.7$ are valid solutions, but $x=0$ isn't, because this doesn't really arise in the first case. In the second case, we see that we cannot have $x=0$ and hence there are no other solutions.

Then the set of solutions is $\{6,-3.7\}$. Done!

Comment: I wouldn't say anything that includes notation such as "$x=6,-3.7,0$" is logically on firm ground.

Comment: That's a well-established shorthand which just means $x \in \{6, -3.7, 0\}$, and is hardly a real problem here. I judged it likely to be closer to the language of equation solving the poster would be familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

Let's go back to the point where you made the step of dividing by $x$. Split your solution into two cases at this point: Case 1, $x\neq 0$. Then it is valid to divide by $x$. However, as you said, once you continue to do algebra you find that $x=0$, which contradicts your assumption. Thus, the case $x\neq 0$ is impossible. Case 2, $x=0$. Plug in $x=0$ and verify that it works. If it also gave a contradiction, then you would conclude there is no solution.

I remember this happening when I took multivariable calculus, doing problems on Lagrange multipliers. I think splitting into cases makes things a bit more clear.